# Can open Telemetry be used to add observability in Apache Pulsar?

Tags: logging, metrics, open-telemetry, apache-pulsar

I'm doing a project with Apache Pulsar and I want to add logging and metrics to the project. Can open Telemetry be used to add observability in Apache Pulsar?
In terms of both adding metrics and tracing?